# c++ Save application window to file yield 'incorrect' area?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, screenshot

I'm slowly making progress in my c++ application.
I would like to 'automate' the repetitive manual screen capture I go through every time in support of my debugging process. I'm relatively new to c++ so I found this snippet that seems to work fine for me, except it's not quite capturing my application area :

```
RECT rectWindow;
GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rectWindow);   // hWnd defined in global scope

int x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h;

x1 = rectWindow.left;   // x1 = 780
y1 = rectWindow.top;    // y1 = 385
x2 = rectWindow.right;  // x2 = 1780
y2 = rectWindow.bottom; // y2 = 1055

// width and height
w = x2 - x1;    // w = 1000
h = y2 - y1;    // h = 670

// copy window to bitmap
HDC     hWindow = GetDC(hWnd);
HDC     hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hWindow);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWindow, w, h);
HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
BOOL    bRet = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, w, h, hWindow, x1, y1, SRCCOPY);

CImage image;
image.Attach(hBitmap);
image.Save(L"C:\\TEMP\\window.bmp", Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);

// clean-up
SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);
DeleteDC(hDC);
::ReleaseDC(NULL, hWindow);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

Below is a manual screen capture of my application window :

[image: result of manual screen capture]

Now, this (saved in JPEG to meet SO min size requirements) is what I'm getting :

[image: BMP image re-saved as JPEG]

Not quite what I expect.
So I edited the Bit Block call this way :

```
BOOL    bRet = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, w, h, hWindow, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

And this gives me "almost" the correct capture :

[image: Almost correct result]

What am  doing wrong?

Comment: Forgot to mention (in case this makes a difference?) that I am in a 'multi-monitor' environment. I tried turning the second monitor off, in case... to no avail.

Comment: If you manually adjusted those numbers instead of trying to compute them, do you get different results?  That's the first thing I would try to do, and that is to discover what numbers actually work correctly (if any).  Then once those numbers are discovered, figure out where/how/ to achieve those numbers programatically.

Comment: Not a dev answer, but FWIW there's a "Problem Steps Recorder" aka PSR tool in every Windows setup for reporting issues https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/record-steps-to-reproduce-a-problem-46582a9b-620f-2e36-00c9-04e25d784e47

Comment: I think I "know" (intuitively) part of what could be going on is that the RectWindow is excluding the Menu area and the application title bar. I tried subtracting 59 pixels from the y1 value, to possibly start capturing "higher up" in the screen to no avail...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is what I "reasoned" in my last comment but it does not seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: I experimented with changing the "location" of the capture area to no avail, there must be a way to "force" the inclusion of the menu and application title I am missing...

Answer (score 1):

`GetWindowRect()` returns screen coordinates, which you are then passing as-is to `BitBlt()`, but it is expecting coordinates relative to the window instead since you are capturing from a window DC and not a screen DC.  That is why the top-left corner of your capture is so far into the window.

Change this:

`BitBlt(..., hWindow, x1, y1, ...)`

To this instead:

`BitBlt(..., hWindow, 0, 0, ...)`

Also, `GetDC()` retrieves an `HDC` for just the *client area* of the window:

> The GetDC function retrieves a handle to a device context (DC) for **the client area of a specified window** or for the entire screen.

Your window's title bar and menu do not appear in your capture because they are outside of the client area.  Since you want a capture of the entire window, use `GetWindowDC()` instead:

> The GetWindowDC function retrieves the device context (DC) for **the entire window, including title bar, menus, and scroll bars**. A window device context permits painting anywhere in a window, because the origin of the device context is the upper-left corner of the window instead of the client area.

Comment: Using the GetWindowDC instead, I got *exactly* what a I need :-)
Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Found some code that worked flawlessly.
It's using a lot of the same code?

```
RECT rcSrc;
HWND hSrcWnd;
HDC hDC2, hSrcDC;
HBITMAP hBmp;
//hSrcWnd = FindWindow(NULL, szWindowClass);

GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rcSrc);

hDC2 = GetDC(hWnd);
hSrcDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC2, rcSrc.right - rcSrc.left, rcSrc.bottom - rcSrc.top);
SelectObject(hSrcDC, hBmp);
PrintWindow(hWnd, hSrcDC, 0);
BitBlt(hDC2, 0, 0, rcSrc.right - rcSrc.left, rcSrc.bottom - rcSrc.top, hSrcDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

CImage image2;
image2.Attach(hBmp);
image2.Save(L"C:\\TMP\\Test.jpg", Gdiplus::ImageFormatJPEG);

DeleteObject(hBmp);
DeleteDC(hSrcDC);
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC2);
```

The result is this :
[image]

Comment: `PrintWindow` is being used.  There is probably a good reason why this is part of the [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-printwindow), as user code would have a difficult time trying to emulate what it does.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sadly, the solution does not "work"? It actually prints the whole application window "inside" the client area? Is there a way I can "retract" my answer?

Comment: There should be a `delete` option.

Comment: "Cheap solution department"... I added an "InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, true);" right after saving the Bitmap to file. It causes an ugly "repaint" of the whole client area *but* it brings the original UI back, so I can "continue" to work. It's far from elegant...